# Multiple routers on one switch. Internet optional

Tags: router, mikrotik-routeros

I confess I'm not an IT guy. I do refrigeration. But I need some help.

I have 13 temperature controllers built by KE2therm with their own IP addresses. I also have a router from KE2 that is built by MikroTik. The KE2 router has 10 physical ports on one side plus one next to the power port. I connect to it by WiFi from my tablet. I can then type in its IP and it will bring up software where I can make changes. Also Port 1 says it's for "internet connection (WAN)". KE2 said I could use a switch to connect more than 10 controllers.

The customer has a router/modem provided by the ISP and a netgear switch. There are 17 unlabeled ethernet cables, 13 of which go to my controllers.

I do not know how to get the KE2 router to connect to the controllers. I want to type in a controllers IP on my tablet and have it come up. I'm assuming 2 routers on one switch may be an issue. Is there anyway I can make this work without figuring out which cable goes where?

In the future I would like to use port forwarding to access the controllers remotely but for now I'm not concerned with the KE2 router accessing the internet unless it's easy to do.

Comment: I will try to draw something shortly. I would really like to use the existing switch for two reasons. One, I dont know which cables go to which devices so it may be difficult to separate my controllers from the other computers etc. Two, getting a switch could be difficult first thing monday. I'm in small town Iowa.

Comment: Easy enough. I still cant figure out how to connect to them but I think that's a software thing. I will call the company monday for that.

Comment: A diagram of what KTTherm want the setup to look like as opposed to what you want may help

Comment: Rather than port forwarding, try a VPN so that your controller is not as exposed.  Lots of folks looking for exposed industrial devices to mess with

Answer (score 1):

The main issues with connecting two routers to a switch are to do with two active DHCP servers 
IF they controllers are fixed addresses then I think/hope that means the KE2Term router does not have a DHCP server and so you should be ok

To test this plug a laptop into one of the 10 ports and see if it gets a (non-auto-generated ) DHCP address  if not then you'll be ok

The Ke2Therm router WAN port will get a IP address from the ISPs router and the Ke2Therm router will have a second IP address for the other 10 ports - which it will use to talk to the TCs the KE2therm temperature controllers (TC) must be connected to one of the 10 ports not the WAN port for the router to access them.

If thats true - connect two cables between the K2Term and the ISP switch, one from the WAN port and one from any of the other ports to any two ports on the ISP switch

This is not a "nice" network - but it should work - at least temporarily until you get a switch

Comment: The TCs can also be configured to use DHCP so I assume the router is capable of that. Perhaps I can shut it off? Also I should connect both cables to the ISP router and not one to the switch?

Comment: Yes I'd think you could shut it off. I sort of assume that these came together preconfigured.  So the router will have an IP address setup and the TCs will also have been setup with IP addresses in the same subnet etc

Comment: Looks to me like it will work either with port forwarding or with the "KE2 Evap version 4.0 firmware" without it - I think my sugggestion will work - but I would advise not leaving it without the extra switch since you have brigded two networks

Comment: They did not come together. So not really pre configured to work together. However all the routers come with the same IP so I assume all TCs are programmed to work with that. I can enter a subnet into the TCs but I honestly dont know what that is. I will do as you said on Monday as well as get a switch ordered.